# How to pass a config file into docker for windows

Tags: windows, docker, redis, configuration

I am trying to run the official latest redis docker image located here:

https://hub.docker.com/_/redis

I want to pass it in a custom config file.

To test I downloaded the sample config file from here:

https://redis.io/topics/config

I stored the file in:

C:/Users//redis/config/redis.config

I changed directory to the redis/config folder (in powershell) and execute the command:

```
docker run -it --rm --name redis --net redis -v ${pwd}:/config redis redis-server redis.conf
```

and I get the following error:

```
Fatal error, can't open config file '/data/redis.conf': No such file or directory
```

I have also tried the command:

```
docker run -it --rm --name redis --net redis -v ${PWD}/config:/etc/redis/ redis redis-server C:\Users\<username>\redis\config\redis.conf
```

Which gives me a similar error:

```
Fatal error, can't open config file '/data/C:\Users\<username>\redis\config\redis.conf': No such file or directory
```

It seems to me that it is looking for the config file local in the containers \data directory...

Shouldn't I be passing it from the local machines file structure?

How do I execute this command from windows so that the local conf is loaded by the containerized machine.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to mount a single file as a volume:

I make the presumption that your `config` file is actually: `C:/Users/redis/config/redis.config`

```
> cd C:/Users/redis
> docker run -it --rm --name redis --net redis -v config/redis.config:/etc/redis/redis.conf redis redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

Your file `C:/Users/redis/config/redis.config` referenced as relative path to `config/redis.conf` because current working directory is `C:\Users\redis`. The `redis` image is build with the convention that `redis-server` is on the path and runs with the parameter to the `.conf` file.